# algorithms- stack and queue

Tags: algorithm, stack, queue

I am doing revision for my exams and I came across this question which I need to find the contents of Q1 after the following code are executed.

The datas

```
5, 7, 12, 4, 0, 4, 6, 8, 67, 34, 23, 5, 0, 44, 33, 22, 6, 0
```

The pusedo-code

```
Q1=createQueue
S1=createStack
loop (not end of file)
    read number 
    if (number not 0)
        pushStack (S1,number)
    else
        popStack (S1,x)
        popStack (S1,x)
        loop (not empty S1)
            popStack (S1,x)
            enqueue (Q1,x)
        end loop
    end if
end loop
```

Here is my solutions

1. if number is not 0, push the numbers to the stack
   so now the stack becomes

   ```
   6
   22
   33
   44 
   5
   23
   34
   67
   8
   6
   4
   4
   12
   7
   5
   ```
2. else pop the first 2 elements of the stack
   so now the stack becomes

   ```
   33
   44 
   5
   23
   34
   67
   8
   6
   4
   4
   12
   7
   5
   ```

3.loop stack !empty, pop the stack and enqueue in Q1.so now the stack is empty and the queue becomes

```
5,7,12,4,4,6,8,67,34,23,5,44,33
```

33 is the first in the queue and 5 is the last of the queue.

I double checked with the answer provided and found out that my answers is different

The provided answer

```
7,5,34,67,8,6,4,33,44
```

I am not sure who is correct. please help.

Comment: The provided answer seems correct. You seem to assume that all the numbers other than zero get pushed onto the stack before anything else happens, but that is incorrect according to the code you provided. Try to work step-by-step up to the first zero, and see what happens. Note that the `if` is nested *inside* the `loop`.

Comment: thank you I will work it out again

Comment: It's trivial to translate this into real code and run it yourself, possibly single-stepping through to see all the intermediate steps. Doing so will teach you more than asking other people to give you the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reasoning is in the correct direction, but there are three zeros  in the input and you only seem to do the `else` logic for the last one. Keep in mind that the else clause is within the loop too. Try processing the input until each of them one by one.